# Html OnClick change background image

Tags: html, css, image, background

Would it be possible to change the background of the html page when clicking a page?

Answer (score 1):

yes, all you have to do is apply a css class that changes the background on the click event, if you can provide a code sniplet i can help you achieve this.

Comment: Wait, can you change the background of the body with the click event?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Change Div Background Image</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    #div1 {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url(images/blue.gif);
    }

    p {
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px
    }

    </style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function changeDivImage()
    {
        var imgPath = new String();
        imgPath = document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage;

        if(imgPath == "url(images/blue.gif)" || imgPath == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/green.gif)";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/blue.gif)";
        }
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <center>
    <p>
        This Javascript Example will change the background image of<br />
        HTML Div Tag onclick event.
    </p>
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Change Background Image" onclick="changeDivImage()" />
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

But if you are using jQuery it would be a lot easier to do ! If you are using jQuery just edit your question

```
$(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        $("body").css("background","url('otherimg.jpg')"); 
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function(){
$("input").click(function(){
    $("body").css({background-image:"url('imageName.gif')"}); 
});
});​
```